# Python, How to get the trough color of a tkinter scrollbar

Tags: tkinter

I need to get the trough color of a tkinter ttk theme scrollbar, I have looked around and can't seem to find any info on it.

I have tried both of the lines below but no luck.

```
hex = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar', 'background')
print(hex)
hex = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.trough', 'background')
print(hex)
```

Neither one of these gives the correct value.

Comment: The correct option is `self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.trough', 'troughcolor')`.  But it is empty for default theme.  If you use other theme, e.g. 'clam', then you can get the color.

Comment: Thank you that was just what I needed.